# Code Beautification: Concatenating Multiple Vars and Strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, concatenation, code-formatting

```
self.homePostalAddress = self.mozillaHomeStreet + "$" + self.mozillaHomeLocalityName + "$" + self.mozillaHomePostalCode + "$$" + self.mozillaHomeCountryName
```

I have this line of code and I'd like to split it into multiple rows as it's becoming too long.

I tried other variants with `#{}` but was not able to achive the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to do this using [String#%](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25) format method:

```
homePostalAddress = "%s$%s$%s$$%s" % [mozillaHomeStreet, mozillaHomeLocalityName,
                                     mozillaHomePostalCode, mozillaHomeCountryName]
```

(You don't need to use `self.` because these methods will be called on self implicitly).

With string interpolation (`#{}`) this code will look like this:

```
 homePostalAddress = "#{mozillaHomeStreet}$#{mozillaHomeLocalityName}$" + 
                     "#{mozillaHomePostalCode}$$#{mozillaHomeCountryName}"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Following Martin correction that '$$' is not a typo.

Use [`#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join) method of Array.

```
homePostalAddress = [
  '$', mozillaHomeStreet, 
  '$', mozillaHomeLocalityName, 
  '$', mozillaHomePostalCode,
  '$$', mozillaHomeCountryName
].join
```

Comment: But OP has two `$$` before  `mozillaHomeCountryName`, in your example there are only one

Comment: I assume this is a typo. In any case adding $ sign to a single variable won't affect readability.

Comment: It is not a typo. It is needed as it's written in the question

Comment: Assuming it would be a typo, you could simply remove the dollars and use `array_of_elements.join("$")`. If the double dollar is actually needed, your solution is fine, but you could also add en empty element and still use `join("$")`. But that's probably not really more readable...

Comment: You see, it's not a typo after all :)